# Is it possible to make the borderColor of the textField inside the tableView change as the text color of the textField changes?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, textfield

I want to change borderColor from lightGray to black when textField is firstResponder. And if the textField resigns again, I want to change it to gray. TextField's textColor changes color automatically without tableView's reload, but borderColor doesn't. Is there a way to change the color by observing the values ​​without reloading the tableView?

```
class ChangePasswordViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var newPasswordTextField: RoundTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkingNewPasswordTextField: RoundTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var explainLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var changePwButton: FillRoundButton!
    
    let viewModel = ChangePasswordViewModel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        
        newPasswordTextField.tag = 0
        checkingNewPasswordTextField.tag = 1

        configureNotificationObservers()
    }
    
    func configureNotificationObservers() {
        newPasswordTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)
        checkingNewPasswordTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    @objc func textDidChange(sender: RoundTextField) {
        if sender == newPasswordTextField {
            viewModel.pwValue = sender.text
        } else {
            viewModel.confirmPwValue = sender.text
        }
        updateForm()
    }
}
```

```
extension ChangePasswordViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.tag == 0 {
            viewModel.pwValue = textField.text ?? ""
        } else {
            viewModel.confirmPwValue = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
}


extension ChangePasswordViewController: FormViewModel {
    func updateForm() {
        changePwButton.isEnabled = viewModel.pwFormIsValid
        newPasswordTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        newPasswordTextField.textColor = .yellow
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZFbf.png)

Comment: You may want to try embedding the textField in a view and messing with the containing view's borderColor.

Comment: Then, should I use the method of observing textField using scrollView rather than tableView? or using tableView reloadRow?

Comment: Not sure. But another thing you should try is setting your textField.layer.borderWidth to a non-zero value.

Comment: borderWidth is set. However, I want to change the border color to red when it is the first responder. In that case, I need to reload the tableView to change the color, but in the case of the button's enable state or textField's textColor, if the value changes without reloading the tableView, the change is reflected on the screen. When reloading the tableView, there is a hassle of saving the textField value in another property and then re-entering it, so I wanted to know a better way.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're doing wrong because you have not shared enough code. Where are you trying to change the border color when the responder status changes?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The color of the border of textField in tableViewCell.

Comment: When TextField is FirstResponder, I want to change the color without reload tableView like textColor. I added a picture.